# How to add color information from csv file to objects

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, color, vertex-colors

I have a csv file with xy coordinates and an additional column that I want use as color information and set as a color ramp. Below is an example of the data I have:

[image]

**Edit:** if the color ramp was to go from red (highest number) to blue (lowest number) then I want the spheres with counts equal to 20 to be red and the sphere with count equal to 1 to be blue.

This is really close to what I want to do: [How do I import XYZ AND a fourth parameter that adds color to my objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173385/how-do-i-import-xyz-and-a-fourth-parameter-that-adds-color-to-my-objects/173392), but I'm not familiar enough with python to get all the way to the end.

This is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated!

```
with open("example.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i==0: continue
        x, y = row[0:2]
    
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add( location = ( float(x), float(y), 0 ) )
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Do you want a _colorramp_ node with colors set at various positions or do you want to set vertex colors on vertices at specific locations or something else altogether?

Comment: My goal is for the numbers in the color column to be mapped to a color ramp gradient. For example, if the color ramp was to go from red (highest number) to blue (lowest number) then I want the spheres with counts equal to 20 to be red and the sphere with count equal to 1 to be blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways you could do it. Here's one:

First create a material all the spheres will use. The nodes should look like:

[image]

- The attribute node reads a custom property on the object named `color`, which should be a number between 0 and 1.
- The color ramp is your desired ramp of course.
- Make note of the name because you'll need it in the script. I called it `Ramp Material`.

Then a slight modification of your script will work

```
import bpy, csv
with open("example.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i==0: continue
        x, y = row[0:2]
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add( location = ( float(x), float(y), 0 ) )

        # This sets the material to use on the sphere you just created
        material = bpy.data.materials["Ramp Material"]
        bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(material)

        # This creates the color custom property (assumes range 0-20)
        bpy.context.object["color"] = float(row[2]) / 20
```